# Microsoft Graph API Excel / Display format / to String / Not Change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to change the display format of a specific column to string using O365 (Python).

Update: update() does not change the display format.
Format_cells.font.bold = True, etc. will be reflected.

If anyone knows how to change the display format to string please let me know.

```
excel_file = WorkBook(excel_file_instance)
ws = excel_file.get_worksheet(f'sheet_name')
format_cells = ws.get_range('S1:S10')
format_cells = format_cells.get_format()

format_cells.font.bold = True # Change OK!

format_cells.range.number_format = '@' # No
format_cells.range.number_format[1][0] = '@' # No

format_cells.update()
```